# How to fix shadow for menu material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I use a few icon menus than box-shadow looks very dark. How to fix that?
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7In9.png): [image]

Codesandbox example https://codesandbox.io/embed/flamboyant-tdd-r83u1

```
   <div>
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <Fragment key={index}>
            <IconButton
              aria-owns={open ? "long-menu" : undefined}
              onClick={this.handleClick}
            >
              <MoreVertIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Menu anchorEl={anchorEl} open={open} onClose={this.handleClose}>
              {options.map(option => (
                <MenuItem key={option} onClick={this.handleClose}>
                  {option}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because, actually you are triggering multiple menus with the same flag at the same time. So shadow is dark because there are multiple menus one after the other.

Answer (score 3):

Below code should fix this, You don't have to render Menu in items loop

```
  render() {
    const items = [...Array(10).keys()];
    const { anchorEl } = this.state;
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

    return (
      <div>
        {items.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <Fragment key={index}>
              <IconButton
                aria-owns={open ? "long-menu" : undefined}
                onClick={this.handleClick}
              >
                <MoreVertIcon />
              </IconButton>

            </Fragment>
          );
        })}


        <Menu anchorEl={anchorEl} open={open} onClose={this.handleClose}>
          {options.map(option => (
            <MenuItem key={option} onClick={this.handleClose}>
              {option}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: It fixed the issue, on open menu Icon click I'm storing the clicked item data in state and when any menu item is clicked on handle I'm using that stored data from state